# Can ZF prove that every set admits a lattice order?

Tags: set-theory, lattice-orders

Can ZF set theory without the axiom of choice prove that every set $S$ can be endowed with a partial order $L$ which is a lattice? And if so, can ZF also prove that every set can be endowed with a partial order which is a distributive lattice? I know that ZF can't prove that every set can be linearly ordered. I would be very interested in knowing the relative strengths of ZF + "every set can be lattice ordered", ZF + "every set can be distributive lattice ordered", and ZF + "every set can be linearly ordered".

Comment: Given a nonempty set $X$ with more than one element, pick $a,b\in X$, $a\neq b$. Then $\{a\}\times X \cup X\times\{b\}$ is a lattice order.

Comment: Pick two elements and call them $\hat{0}, \hat{1}$ and for any $x \in S \setminus \{\hat{0}, \hat{1}\}$, define $\hat{0} < x < \hat{1}$.  This gives a partial order which is a lattice.  It's not distributive, but it should show that "every set can be lattice ordered" is trivial,.

Comment: @BrianMoehring snap!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin by two seconds! :-) (and only because I deleted a logically deficient first comment!)

Comment: Re: the distributive lattice question, assume the continuum hypothesis is false and let $X$ be a set of cardinality strictly between the integers and the reals. Does anyone see a way to write down a distributive lattice structure on $X$?

Comment: @bof: ah, because it injects into $\mathbb{R}$? Fair enough; what about a set of cardinality strictly between $\aleph_1$ and $2^{\aleph_1}$? Basically I only know how to put a lattice structure on power sets and ordinals and I assume this isn't enough to cover arbitrarily large cardinalities in the absence of choice.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: $2^\kappa$, for any $\aleph$ number $\kappa$, can be linearly ordered.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I wish people would just tell me the constructions they have in mind, but thinking about it a bit, do you mean the lexicographic order on subsets?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Yes, I mean the lexicographic order. Sorry. I'm too used to it being somehow obvious at this point...

Comment: What about a set of cardinality strictly between $\mathfrak c$ and $2^\mathfrak c$?

Comment: @bof: There can be a subset of $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ which is amorphous, while it's not "between", it may very well be that if we take the sum of two incomparable cardinals (here, $\frak c$ and the amorphous set), then any structure on the union must be somewhat of a direct sum of the two structures. Or something like that. So I can see how there might not be any distributive lattice structure of size $|A|+\frak c$, where $A$ is amorphous.

Answer (score 4):

Working in ZF.

It has been pointed out in comments that any set can be ordered as a complete modular lattice, namely, with all elements incomparable except the top and bottom elements.

It is consistent that there are sets which can't be distributive-lattice ordered, namely, any [amorphous set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set). An amorphous set is an infinite set which does not contain two disjoint infinite subsets. It's consistent with ZF that such sets exist.

**Proposition.** No amorphous lattice is distributive.

**Proof.** Let $L$ be an amorphous lattice. We call $x$ a *successor* of $y$ if $x\gt y$, a *predecessor* of $y$ if $x\lt y$; "almost all" means "all but finitely many."

Suppose infinitely many (therefore almost all) elements have infinitely many successors. Let $S$ be the (cofinite) set of all elements with infinitely many successors (and therefore only a finite number of predecessors). Then each $x\in S$ has a successor $y\in S$, and $y$ has more predecessors than $x$. Thus the number of predecessors of an element takes infinitely many different (finite) values, which is impossible since $L$ is amorphous. We conclude that almost all elements have finitely many successors.

Let $A$ be the (cofinite) set of all elements with finitely many successors. Let $A_n$ be the set of all elements with exactly $n$ successors. Since $A$ is amorphous, one of the sets $A_n$ is cofinite; fix that $n$. Let $F=L\setminus A_n$.

Plainly $A_n$ is an antichain; thus, if $x,y\in A_n$, $x\ne y$, then $x\land y\in F$ and $x\lor y\in F$. Since $F$ is a finite set, it follows by the finite Ramsey theorem that there are three distinct elements $x,y,z\in A_n$ with $x\land y=x\land z=y\land z$ and $x\lor y=x\lor z=y\lor z$. That is, $L$ embeds the nondistributive diamond lattice $M_3$, and $x\land(y\lor z)\gt(x\land y)\lor(x\land z)$.

**Comment.** This is only a partial answer, as I have no idea whether "every set can be distributive-lattice ordered" is weaker than "every set can be linearly ordered."

Comment: I completely missed that! I apologize, great answer